# How to fix RewriteBase on drupal8

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-8

problem: I have drupal (8.6) installed on my server and I want it to be accessible by `"/drupal" (mysite.com/drupal)`, I've used either `htaccess` and `apache2 conf's RewriteBase /drupal`, but when I click on connect or anylink in my drupal website it gets me redirected without `/drupal`, ex: `mysite.com/user/login`.

apache2 conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
ServerName mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sitesweb/drupal

<Directory /var/www/sitesweb/drupal>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /drupal
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    php_value memory_limit 512M
</Directory>
LogLevel debug
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/drupal_error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

And on my .htaccess either i comment or uncomment the RewriteBase line, same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try solution from here:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241761/how-do-i-run-a-site-from-a-sub-directory

That is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !drupal/
  RewriteRule (.*) /drupal/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hmm.. it should. Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?